# Suggest different color combination based on current css

Tags: html, css, colors, color-scheme

Is there a tool that suggests different color combinations based on current css.

Also any tool that just gives me web safe color combinations would be helpful.

I looking for a tool that suggests what should be a button color what should be a link color a nd like of

Comment: Don't worry too much (if at all) about 'web-safe' colours any more; I think, currently, all monitors can accurately and reliably display the full 24-bit colour palette.

Comment: Hope this will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429150/similar-color-shades-codes

Comment: Do you need something to help you pick a color scheme for your site?  Or are you building a site that will automatically suggest colors?

Comment: first one . I looking for suggestions like what should be a button color what should be a link color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for "color palette rating site"

They are a *Stackoverflow* of sorts for color combinations:

- [Kuler](http://kuler.adobe.com/)
- [Colour Lovers](http://www.colourlovers.com/palettes/top)
- [Color Scheme Designer](http://colorschemedesigner.com/)
- [Color Schemer](http://www.colorschemer.com/schemes/)